# TensorFlow - What's the difference between NodeDef and OpDef?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I would like to know the difference bewteen NodeDef and OpDef in TensorFlow.

`tf.Operation` represents a graph node in a TensorFlow Graph. It takes `node_def` and a graph as input. What makes me confused is that it also takes `op_def` as an optional input. In my understanding, a node can only correspond to one operation. So why bother?

```py
tf.Operation(
    node_def, g, inputs=None, output_types=None, control_inputs=None,
    input_types=None, original_op=None, op_def=None
)
```

Answer (score 0):

According to proper `tensorflow` documentation:

```
Optional. The op_def_pb2.OpDef proto that describes the op type that this Operation represents.
```

It's an optional argument that allows you to **describe** the `op type` of your `Operation`.

https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Operation